# Bootstrap weird border on hover on image inside nav class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I get this weird white/gray border on hover on image inside nav class.

[image: Normal Image]

[image: On hover]

How do I get rid of it?

Here's the code

```
          <ul class="nav nav-pills">
            <li class = "list">
            <a href="#/events" class = "link"><img src = "images/Icon-Events.png" class = "nav-image"></a>
            <center><span class = "description">Events</span></center>
          </li>
         </ul>
```

Comment: are you sure the white/grey background is not part of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix. Will post it here in case it helps someone.

In the bootstrap css file (bootstrap.min.css or bootstrap.css depending on which you have included in your app) override

```
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: #eee;
}
```

with

```
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the hover effect of the `.nav`.

You can either remove the `.nav` class if you don't need it, or simply override it's `:hover` style with your own css.

Comment: I need a nav because it's a navigation bar.

Comment: How do I override it?
.nav:hover{//what}

Comment: try `background:transparent`

Comment: @zack add css to the question as well. or it would be great if you create a fiddle